# HTML-Doctype kills css declaration "height: 100%;"

Tags: html, css, doctype

I've been working on a layout for a web page and even though I got it running in a minimalistic example it refuses to work when transferred to my sites template.

First I thought that some CSS rules or else would interfere, but I narrowed it down to the doctype:

If I run the following example in chrome, everything works fine. But as soon as I add a doctype (no matter if html, xhtml, strict, transitional or loose), its messed up. and my "messed up" i mean the the css directive "height: 100%;" is completely ignored for the div with the id "container".

Can someone give me a hint where the problem is?

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
body
{
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#container
{
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px dashed black;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#header
{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#main
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid green;
}

#inner
{
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">header</div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="inner">
            inner
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here's a simple and clear explanation of the DOCTYPE issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32215263/3597276

Answer (score 0):

I'd be setting the following in CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
```

As `height` inherits from its parent element.

Comment: It needs to be height, body and any other ancestor elements.