# doctype kills 100% but not if doctype is closed?

Tags: css, html, doctype

I'm trying to make something 100% height and adding a doctype breaks that. That was explained on [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952345/html-doctype-kills-css-declaration-height-100?lq=1). 
  However, I found something weird -- if I close the doctype tag (which I know you're not supposed to do) then 100% height works again on both chrome and IE. What exactly is happening then? Does closing the doctype mean the doctype is being ignored?

```
    <!doctype html/> <!--You're not supposed to close doctype but if you do, then 
the 100% sizing works. Why?-->
<html>
<body>
    <!--This 100% height won't work with a normal doctype but closing
    the doctype makes it work?-->
    <div style="border:5px solid black;height:100%">This should be 100%</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you're making it invalid triggering quirks mode?

Answer (score 1):

According to [8.1.1 The DOCTYPE](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#the-doctype),

> A DOCTYPE must consist of the following components, in this order:
>
> 1. A string that is an [ASCII case-insensitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#ascii-case-insensitive) match for the string "
>
>    One or more [space characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-character).
>
>    A string that is an [ASCII case-insensitive](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#ascii-case-insensitive) match for the string "html".
>
>    Optionally, a [DOCTYPE legacy string](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#doctype-legacy-string) or an [obsolete permitted DOCTYPE string](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#obsolete-permitted-doctype-string) (defined below).
>
>    Zero or more [space characters](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-character).
>
>    A ">" (U+003E) character.

Therefore, your "closed doctype" is an invalid doctype. And thus it's like you had no doctype at all.